# Python Celery run set of functions on set on envs without overlapping

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery

Trying to run following case with Celery:

Example:

- have set of different tests (each is a dict with args to use)
- have 5 different environments to run those tests.

I can execute one test simultaneously (multiprocessing) on 5 evns. Now trying to make in on Celery.

The problem is how tests were executed, they should not overlap in one env.

So one env should run only one test at the same time, but Celery with workers and queues can execute them all it total mashup. I tried to use "Canvas primitives" and add "test + evns" in loop.

Like:

```
tests_set_list =  [{test1}, {test2}, {test3}]
envs_list = [{alpha}, {bravo}, {charlie}, {delta}, {echo}]
```

variant 1:
In this case all tasks were added into the queue end executes just one by one, without any order, so they overlapping.

```
"""This loop create tasks for each env"""
for env_item in envs_list:
    for test_item in tests_set_list:
        r_key = 'tests_run.bunch_test_execute_task.{0}.{1}'.format(test_item['test_folder_name'],
                                                                   env_item['env_codename'])
        bunch_test_execute_task.apply_async(kwargs={'env_item': env_item,
                                                    'test_item': [test_item],
                                                    'tkn_branch': branch,
                                                    },
                                            queue='tests_run',
                                            routing_key=r_key)
```

variant 2: --> TypeError: 'AsyncResult' object is not subscriptable
In this case tasks only add first iteration and then stop.

```
""" This loop create env inst for each task. Works in group
    Works bad, did not add task in worker queue. 
"""
list_of_groups = []
for test_item in tests_set_list:
    tasks_group_by_env = []
    for env_item in synced_envs:
        r_key = 'tests_run.bunch_test_execute_env_q_task.{0}.{1}'.format(test_item['test_folder_name'],
                                                                          env_item['env_codename'])
        task = bunch_test_execute_env_q_task(env_item, [test_item], branch)
        tasks_group_by_env.append(task)
    groups = group(tasks_group_by_env)
    list_of_groups.append(groups)

for group_item in list_of_groups:
    # job = group(*group_item)
    job = group_item
    job.apply_async(queue='tests_run')
```

variant 3: --> TypeError: unorderable types: float() >= str()
but anyway tasks was added in queue, but execute with overlapping.

```
""" This loop use one test item and iter envs from list of synced envs to add groups """
list_of_groups = []
for test_item in tests_set_list:
    r_key = 'tests_run.bunch_test_execute_env_q_task.{0}.{1}'
    lazy_group = group(bunch_test_execute_env_q_task.apply_async(
          args=[env_item['env_codename']],
          kwargs={'env_item': env_item,
                  'test_item': [test_item],
                  'tkn_branch': branch,
                  },
          queue='tests_run',
          routing_key=r_key.format(test_item['pattern_folder_name'],
                                   env_item['env_codename']))for env_item in envs_list)
    # list_of_tasks.append(task)
    list_of_groups.append(lazy_group)

all_groups = group(*list_of_groups)
all_groups()
```

What I want to achieve in summary:
Each test get separate test env. for it and this is one separate job:

```
job_1 = alpha(test1)
job_2 = bravo(test1)
job_3 = charlie(test1)
job_4 = delta(test1)
job_5 = echo(test1)
...
job_n+1 = alpha(test_n+1)
job_n+1 = bravo(test_n+1)
job_n+1 = charlie(test_n+1)
job_n+1 = delta(test_n+1)
job_n+1 = echo(test_n+1)
```

This looks like can be achieved simply by adding separate worker for each test env, so they never overlap each other, because run in separate processes-workers, but it's not elegant, because environments can change time to time.

Comment: Checked almost the same logic but with separate worker for each env. passed args queue=ENV_NAME and routing key for each. In Celery config just added unique consumer for each ENV_NAME. And it;s worked. (N.b. group execution still give error "float() >= str()")

Comment: Final: worked as planned when you use just a separate woker for each "thread" and this worker configured only to contribute from it's queue. So you just send task to named queue and it goes to it's own worker. You can also add/remove workers and queues(contributors) right on fly in code. So when you have a bunch of tasks - make bunch of workers for each task "theme". It will work fine, but IMHO looks excessive. I'd rather use logical grouping of chains, but they won't work as I want in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use queues:

How it looks like on py:
- this is only to add a queue to the existing worker. How to add workers - see celery demonizing doc.

```
app.control.add_consumer(
    queue='alpha',
    exchange = 'tests_run',
    exchange_type = 'direct',
    routing_key   = 'alpha.*',
    destination = ['alpha@tentacle'])
```

Then, when you want to execute 5 different tasks simultaneously without any overlapping (for example you use 5 diff envs) you just add the task with:

queue="desirable_queue"

```
TestExecTasks().your_task.apply_async(
    args=[arg1,arg2],
    kwargs=dict(test=test_set, env=some_env),
    queue=queue, routing_key=r_key,
    soft_time_limit=HOURS_2, task_time_limit=HOURS_2+500)
```

What does it mean?
You could have workers which represent each of your working environment:

- alpha, beta, charlie, delta, echo

So you execute one task in for-loop, each with env you wanted to. All tasks will run each on their worker because workers have unique queues attached. So you need to have 5 workers + 5 queues. And this did the trick. Of course, you can include even threading in each task process and make even more.